# Seaborn barplot behaves unexpectedly with dodge argument

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, bar-chart

I am trying to produce a nested barplot with seaborn.
Without the dodge argument, the plot looks like this

`sns.barplot(data=pos_data, x='bin', y='%', hue='POS')`

[image: Real data distribution]

Now I want to nest 4 bars (n, v, a, r), but when I use the dodge=False argument, the plot loses one of the properties, namely, it does not show v; however, it still appears in the legend.

`sns.barplot(data=pos_data, x='bin', y='%', hue='POS', dodge=False)`

[image: Seaborn has lost one of the values]

All the (n, v, a, r) values should sum to 1. I was able to plot something similar to what I need using pyplot, so the result should look similar to this:

[image: How the result should look like]

The dataframe I am using is below

```py
data = {'bin': [0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 0.16, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.38, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.62, 0.62, 0.62, 0.62, 0.73, 0.73, 0.73, 0.73, 0.84, 0.84, 0.84, 0.84, 0.94, 0.94, 0.94, 0.94], '%': [0.55, 0.15, 0.26, 0.05, 0.46, 0.12, 0.33, 0.09, 0.46, 0.12, 0.36, 0.06, 0.43, 0.1, 0.44, 0.03, 0.39, 0.06, 0.53, 0.02, 0.34, 0.07, 0.58, 0.01, 0.3, 0.11, 0.58, 0.01, 0.41, 0.1, 0.49, 0.0], 'POS': ['n', 'v', 'a', 'r', 'n', 'v', 'a', 'r', 'n', 'v', 'a', 'r', 'n', 'v', 'a', 'r', 'n', 'v', 'a', 'r', 'n', 'v', 'a', 'r', 'n', 'v', 'a', 'r', 'n', 'v', 'a', 'r']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

While I was able to make the plot with matplotlib, I am not satisfied with the result and I would like to be able to plot it with seaborn, and understand why the dodge parameter behaves unexpectedly so as to hide one of the dimensions.

Comment: `ax = df.pivot(index='bin', columns='POS', values='%').plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, rot=0)` seems to be the best option. `seaborn` is just an API for `matplotlib` and `pandas` uses `matplotlib` as the default plotting backend. Plotting is all about shaping the data for the API. Reshape with `.pivot` and the **best** option for stacked bars is to plot directly with `panda.DataFrame.plot`.

Comment: The issue with `dodge=False` is that it's not meant to stack the bars. As you can see, the bars are plotted front to back, and `v` is smaller than `a`, so it's hidden. `n` is also smaller than `a` for some bins, and is hidden.

Comment: `dodge=False` is best used in cases where `hue` is used, but there is only one bar for each x-axis value

Comment: I see now,  and with ```sns.set()``` I can get the seaborn look, which I was after. Thanks a lot! This solves the problem.

Comment: You can just use `plt.style.use("seaborn-darkgrid")` then there's no need to import seaborn see the style docs for additional seaborn options. And use `ec='white'` inside `.plot(...ex='white')`

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney while the "seaborn" stylesheets that matplotlib ships are probably good enough for most people, I would not recommend using them as they do not contain some important fixes/updates that have been made to parameter definitions that seaborn uses.

Answer (score 1):

The solution below allows to compare the values of the bars,
but **it is not stacking**.

As it appears that bars are drawn in the order the rows appear in the dataframe - to visualize all the bars you can sort the data in the descending order of Y-value before feeding it to sns.barplot

```py
sorted_data = pos_data.sort_values(by="%", ascending=False)
sns.barplot(data=sorted_data, x='bin', y='%', hue='POS', dodge=False)
```

This should result in the following graph:

[image]